# Downloaded ZIP from from CodeSandbox (Vue.JS page) index.html produces blank page

Tags: html, vue.js, leaflet

[My first ever Vue.JS / Vue2Leaflet app](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2leaflet-custom-icons-npd4i?file=/App.vue) works fine on codesandbox.io, but when I download the ZIP and open the index.html file, it is blank?

Do I need to do something to the code base (compile? install additional dependencies?) before it works? I am looking for something I can upload on a server...

Alternatively, how difficult would it be to convert this to a single .html page? (Single File Component?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how this project is configured but I advise you to convert it to a default @vue/cli setup.

```
npm install && npm install -D @vue/cli-service @vue/cli-plugin-babel vue-template-compiler postcss-import postcss-url && npm install core-js
```

Edit .babelrc so it just contains:

```
{
  "presets": ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"]
}
```

- Create public folder and move index.html in it.
- Create src folder then move App.vue and index.js into it
- Rename index.js to main.js
- Edit main.js to replace `template: '<App/>', components: { App }` by `render: h => h(App)`
- Delete build and config folders

Edit package.json to add

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build"
}
```

And run either `npm run serve` or `npm run build`

Also, in App.vue :

- Replace `:key="office.id"` by `:key="'office' + office.id"`
- Replace `:key="factory.id"` by `:key="'factory' + factory.id"`
- Replace `:key="warehouse.id"` by `:key="'warehouse' + warehouse.id"`

(because you can't have the same components (l-marker) within the same parent with the same keys)

Comment: Thank you for your involved breakdown! Learning more and more Vue every day. Since yesterday, I've come to understand that what I'm requesting is not actually called Single File Component (SFC) and maybe you can enlighten me a bit. What's it called when I just wish to use Vue in a single .html file (no external package.json, index.js etc.) with everything loading from CDN? I'm wondering if I could possibly convert what I have made on CodeSandbox back into what I initially made on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AnonymousCaptain/wqypr814/

Comment: Like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-leaflet-cdn-n5603?file=/index.html